# Which Definition Should Be Used for Relative Maximum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definition

1. Look at the graph of $f$:
   [image]
2. Below is the definition of a relative maximum that I am [using](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/local-maxima-and-minima-and-absolute-maxima-and-minima):

   > **Definition:** Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. We say $c\in X$ is a relative maximum of $f(x)$ if $\exists(a, b)\subseteq X$: $a<c<b$ and $\forall x\in (a, b)$ $f(x)\leq f(c)$.

Looking at the **answer** found in $2.$ a neighborhood containing $-3$ can be any set $N$ satisfying: $[-3, \delta-3)\subseteq N \subseteq X$ for some $\delta>0$. Therefore, having $N=[-3, \delta-3)$ where $\delta=1$ would clearly result in $f(-3)$ being called a "relative maximum."

This is a problem because my definition does not state $-3$ would be a relative maximum as there is no open interval containing $-3$ here. The domain of $f$ cannot stretch out that far.

**Question:** If one were teaching Calculus, what definition is better to use? Is $f(x)$ a relative maximum at $x=-3$ here or not...

Comment: The subset $[-3,4]$ with the [subspace/relative topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) has $[-3,-3+\delta)$ as open.

Comment: I view that as a half-open interval and not an open interval. The definition of open sets change based on what topology is being used. Is the definition of local maximum using that $[-3, -3+\delta)$ is an open set here in context to topology or is it an ordinary open-interval? The context of how one defines an interval change depending on what book one is reading. So, what is the definition that is right here?

Comment: You can define and call things whatever you like. What is important is how they interact. At $-3$ that function takes a value that is larger than the values that the function takes at all points in the domain that are closer to $-3$ than $-2$. That's all that matter. As such satisfies what the concept of relative maximum is about for the function $f:[-3,4]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requiring $(a,b)\subset X$ as in your definition, the usual definition would instead require that $f(x)\leq f(c)$ for all $x \in X \cap (a,b)$ (where $a < c < b$).

With this (usual) definition, your solution is correct.

With the (unusual) definition that you cite, the point -3 would not be a local (or relative) maximum.

Comment: Why require $b<c$ here?

Comment: @W.G.: Thanks, typo. I meant $a <c < b$, so that $c$ is contained in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

For teaching, you ought use the definition used in the text.  Since this definition usually only applies to points in the interior of the domain [as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$], we should not call the point at $x=-3$ a relative max in the classroom.

That said, in almost every discussion I have had with other teachers at the college level, we concluded the appropriate definition for boundary points is via the subspace topology, which means it ought to be a "relative max" in the generalized definition.

Comment: So, in the context of college calculus, would one say that is a relative max or not? In the context of topology, is it different?

Comment: For both books I have taught from, we would have either said it's not a relative max or it is inconclusive.  This decision,however, was made during coordination meetings, as the definition given in the text didn't apply to boundary points.

Comment: Awful, just awful. That decision sounds like the type of garbage one finds in Stewart's Calculus. It is only setting up students for failure.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I don't even see your point.  The only decision I shared was the one that we shouldn't extend the definition's application beyond that given in the primary text.  This is exactly like a differential geometry text defining a property for manifolds without specifying whether it can be extended to manifolds-with-boundary.  If we want to extend it later, we can.  Where would a student be set up for failure by not knowing a broader definition? (which e.g. has an unnatural interpretation when the domain is discrete)

Comment: As an alternative, if you're saying that the choice of text was garbage (making your mention of Stewart less of a non sequitur) then I agree with you, but that's not really the point here.  Besides, like many I was never in a position to even have a say for the text.

Comment: Because the instructor knows or should know how concepts get extended and how they interact with future knowledge. Even if the students will only work with functions everywhere defined on $\mathbb{R}$. It is the instructors' job to made them note that there is nothing useful in including or excluding end-points of intervals in that definition, but that all nearby points getting smaller values. That the students are being set up for failure can be seen right here. The OP is likely a student getting their first taste of teaching or tutoring and is confused about it.

Comment: I know that some universities are used to teach like if it were primary school. They pick a text book and they teach like if knowledge ends where the book ends, but university should make people ready to go on their own and learn from any source available. A choice of text book should only be a starting point, and maybe as an easy place from where to assign exercises.